# Node.js caught error undefined but defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been working on a bot for 12 days now and I need to upgrade to v12. Everything was going smoothly until I tried a command that will give a specified role to a mentioned user.

I have 2 variables. One is a role variable that the user has specified and the member variable (which is equaled to message.guild.members.get(args[0])).

The code looks like this:

```js
let Member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(arguments[0]);
    if (!Member) return message.channel.send("Error: Either the member does not exist or you haven't put the member to give the role to!");
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === arguments[1]) || message.guild.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === arguments[1]) || message.mentions.roles.first();
    if (!role) return nessage.channel.send("Error: Please provide a valid role!");
    
    // if (role === "undefined") {
        // let role = message.guild.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === arguments[1]) || message.guild.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === arguments[1]) || message.mentions.roles.first();
    // }
    
    if (Member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
        return message.channel.send("Error: The mentioned user already has that role!");
    } else {
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === arguments[1]) || message.guild.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === arguments[1]) || message.mentions.roles.first();
        console.log(message);
        console.log("role" + role);
        Member.roles.add(role.id).catch(e => console.log("Error: " + e.message));
    }
```

The code looked fine to me and expected it to work, but then I got an error in the console. It doesn't say what variable is not defined, it just says it's undefined.

I tried checking if the role variable is undefined, but I commented out since it didn't work. Then, I have let it print the message and check if the role is undefined. The role variable is fine. The message variable is fine. Even the Member variable is fine.

I use the latest Node.js.

Here's the console log:

```
Message {
  channel: TextChannel {
    type: 'text',
    deleted: false,
    id: '729663938148565134',
    name: 'general',
    rawPosition: 0,
    parentID: '729663938148565132',
    permissionOverwrites: Collection [Map] {},
    topic: 'Beware, there will be a lot of mentions.',
    nsfw: undefined,
    lastMessageID: '733951355240316948',
    rateLimitPerUser: 0,
    lastPinTimestamp: 1594845448699,
    guild: Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '729663937557168181',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'Bot Testing',
      icon: null,
      splash: null,
      region: 'europe',
      memberCount: 6,
      large: false,
      features: [],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelID: null,
      systemChannelID: '729663938148565134',
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'MEDIUM',
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1594035922599,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      vanityURLCode: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
      ownerID: '402159567200583680',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    },
    messages: MessageManager {
      cacheType: [Function: LimitedCollection],
      cache: [LimitedCollection [Map]],
      channel: [Circular]
    },
    _typing: Map { '402159567200583680' => [Object] }
  },
  deleted: false,
  id: '733951355240316948',
  type: 'DEFAULT',
  content: '>giveRole <@!655895332722442282> Mod',
  author: User {
    id: '402159567200583680',
    bot: false,
    username: 'KFM',
    discriminator: '3147',
    avatar: '5f322e4ab3ec14e9fa83e1c77d8bb36d',
    lastMessageID: '733951355240316948',
    lastMessageChannelID: '729663938148565134',
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 }
  },
  pinned: false,
  tts: false,
  nonce: '733951341017169920',
  system: false,
  embeds: [],
  attachments: Collection [Map] {},
  createdTimestamp: 1595058039246,
  editedTimestamp: null,
  reactions: ReactionManager {
    cacheType: [Function: Collection],
    cache: Collection [Map] {},
    message: [Circular]
  },
  mentions: MessageMentions {
    everyone: false,
    users: Collection [Map] { '655895332722442282' => [User] },
    roles: Collection [Map] {},
    _members: Collection [Map] { '655895332722442282' => [GuildMember] },
    _channels: null,
    crosspostedChannels: Collection [Map] {}
  },
  webhookID: null,
  application: null,
  activity: null,
  _edits: [],
  flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  reference: null
}
roletrue
Error: undefined
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It looks like the role.id is undefined. I will try to see how to fix that.

Comment: are u trying to callout `Error: undefined` at the end of ur console log? if so , it just means that ur exception has no message defined!!!

Comment: @CrossScript you need to find how id looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem with this part of code

```
    console.log("role" + role); // true
    Member.roles.add(role.id).catch(e => console.log("Error: " + e.message));
```

You trying add `undefined` in roles, because:

```js
const roleId = (true).id;
console.log(roleId); //undefined
```

Your got your **Boolean** from [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function which always return `true` or `false`, try change this to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

try add some **id** like 733951355240316948.

I dont know how looks `role.id`, but role must be `Object`

for example:

```
{
  id:'asdasdawe3534536456',
  // other fields
}
```

You need find what expect `.add` function in `Member.roles.add`

Comment: I tried the suggestion and it appears the role and the message variables aren't defined which is weird since, at the end of the function, it says "HAIL 2 U". Also, when you meant some id, did you meant I should type Member.roles.add.some(role.id).catch(e => console.log("Error: " + e.message));

I don't have that much good experience in Node.js
Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @CrossScript **id** must looks like **733951355240316948**. Id it's a sting not a **Boolean** type

Comment: I know how a role id looks like. It's just weird that it's a boolean. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @CrossScript it's because you use some, try use find

Comment: Tried it, and it worked!

I am upgrading to v12 and I tried using .find but it didn't work. It looks like I only need to put .cache before .find

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CrossScript happy to help you))